# jQuery mobile is changing my images src attribute

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-mobile

I am building a site with jQuery Mobile and I am using ajax to change between pages.

I have a footer like this:

```
<footer data-role="footer">
    <h4>
       <a href="http://www.mysite.com/map" rel="external">
          <img src="http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/img/icon_mapa.png" />
       </a>
       <a href="http://www.mysite.com/english" rel="external">
          <img src="http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/img/en.jpg" />
       </a>
    </h4>
</footer>
```

In the index page, it works fine. But when I go to another page, and this page is added to the DOM, I can see the images for a moment and then, something is updating my images src.

For example if my img src is http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/img/es.jpg

and I request this page http://www.mysite.com/?lang=en#/category/actividades/?lang=en

something is updating my image src to http://www.mysite.com/category/actividades/?lang=enwp-content/themes/twentyeleven/img/icon_mapa.png

Comment: @Jasper you where right, changing my images URL to /wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/img/es.jpg fixed my troubles :) Can you answer my question with your comment so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume mysite.com is an example, can we see the working code?

It appears to be a baseURL issue but it appears as though you are using absolute URLs in your links (normally baseURL creates issues when using relative paths).